# Using MinGW-w64 with Visual Studio Code without adding it to the PATH

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, mingw, mingw-w64

I have always used Code::Blocks as my IDE for MinGW-w64 on Windows.
However, I notice a lot of people on stackoverflow are using Visual Studio Code these days, so maybe it's time I gave that a try.

According to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw I should add MinGW-w64 to the PATH, but I really don't want to do this. I have several versions of my personal build of MinGW-w64 (http://winlibs.com/) on my system, and adding these to the PATH would risk mixing them up.

So is there a way to use MinGW-w64 with Visual Studio Code without adding it to the PATH?

Comment: How do you want to execute your mingw exes? via some extension or in the vscode terminal? Also, have you installed the c/c++ extension?

Comment: Before installing I wanted to know the best way to do it. Plan was to install the C/C++ extension, yes.

Comment: You can customize everything you want regarding debugging/compiling etc if you install VSCode extension, you can have a complete isolated environment ignoring your system path variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [C/C++ Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools), 
You can set all the settings from clang to compiler with whatever paths you want, ignoring the system path.

[image: Example Settings..]

You can find all the configurable settings here: [C++ Extension Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/customize-default-settings-cpp)

However System Path is needed for VSCode's internal terminal to work as its just a Wrapper to which ever terminal you are using.

Unless you have your own bash configured on windows which points your custom paths.

Let me know if you have any questions.